# Argument for index in function

Tags: python

I'm making a function and I want it so that you can enter a index of a list as a parameter, how can I do this?

```
Map = {'room11' : [[1,1,1,2,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,2],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],
       'room21' : [[1,1,1,2,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,0,2],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],
       'room31' : [[1,1,1,2,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],
       'room12' : [[1,1,1,2,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,2],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,2,1,1,1]],
       'room22' : [[1,1,1,2,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,0,2],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,2,1,1,1]],
       'room32' : [[1,1,1,2,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,2,1,1,1]],
       'room13' : [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,2],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,2,1,1,1]],
       'room23' : [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,0,2],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,2,1,1,1]],
       'room33' : [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,2,1,1,1]]
       }
```

I want something like this(this obviously doesn't work):

```
def move_up(coor):
    return Map['room<num>'][x+1][y])
```

So if I were to do this:

```
move_up(Map['room11'][1][1])
```

it would return this:

```
Map['room11'][2][1]
```

Comment: Well done for posting code which “obviously doesn’t work”. So many new programmers are not brave enough to take that step, but this is exactly the right forum for this sort of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass Map and coord in like this:

```
def move_up(Map, coord):
    x, y = coord
    return Map['room<num>'][x+1][y])

# call like this:
move_up(Map, (1, 1) )
```

**Update:**

If you want to pass the room in as well, then that's fine:

```py
def move_up(Map, room, coord):
    x, y = coord
    return Map[room][x+1][y])

# call like this:
move_up(Map, 'room12', (1, 1) )
```

Comment: You did help me a lot, now my code is this:

def move_up(room, coord):
    List, Index = coord # I figured list and index are more precise variables
    return Map[room][List+1][Index]

move_up(Map('room11'), (1, 1) )

I'm getting a TypeError because dictionaries are not callable.

EDIT: Didn't notice that the code would be hard to read

Comment: Oh, I don't know why I commented that, the error was pretty self explanatory, I just need to call it without a using dict, thank you!