# Function knowing index of value being passed to it

Tags: python, indexing

So, I want to make a function but I want it to also know what index of the value is being passed to it as said in the title. 
Here is my code:

```
Map = {'room11' : [[1,1,1,2,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,2],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],
       'room21' : [[1,1,1,2,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,0,2],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],
       'room31' : [[1,1,1,2,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],
       'room12' : [[1,1,1,2,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,2],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,2,1,1,1]],
       'room22' : [[1,1,1,2,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,0,2],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,2,1,1,1]],
       'room32' : [[1,1,1,2,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,2,1,1,1]],
       'room13' : [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,2],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,2,1,1,1]],
       'room23' : [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,0,2],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,2,1,1,1]],
       'room33' : [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,2,1,1,1]]
       }

def get_list(room):
    return (???)
```

I want it to return this when it is called:

```
# I'm calling it
get_list(Map[room11][3][0])

# And this is what I want it to return
3
```

It is getting the 3 from Map[room][**3**][0]
Can someone tell me how to do so?

Comment: How `3`? You don't have `3` anywhere in your `Map`.

Comment: You are just passing the function an integer — the value found at `(Map[room11][3][0]`. In other words you are calling this with `get_list(1)`. The function doesn't know you are trying to get `room11` index `3`, etc. because that's all evaluated before the function is called.

Comment: Also, it's not clear how why you didn't learn this from your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363090/argument-for-index-in-function

Comment: Well, does that mean that this is not possible? I figured that this question might  be better phrased then last. And I was hoping that you can do this without adding any parameters.

Comment: No, it's not possible in this way. The function does not know what you did to get the value you passed to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument for index in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363090/argument-for-index-in-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the map and the indices, and let the function do the indexing:

```
def example(data, room, x, y):
    print(f'The value at ({x}, {y}) in room {room} is {data[room][x][y]}')

get_list(Map, 'room11', 3, 0)
```

Or depending on what the function is actually for, maybe it makes more sense to just pass the room data (like `Map['room11']`) and coordinates. You get the idea.